# System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension threw an exception

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

I got this error in a WPf Application when calling the InitializeComponent. In the Designer I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'LCP.ScanLite.WindowsWPF, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.BaseUriHelper.GetLoadedAssembly(String assemblyName, String assemblyVersion, String assemblyKey)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourceContainer.GetResourceManagerWrapper(Uri uri, String& partName, Boolean& isContentFile)
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourceContainer.GetPartCore(Uri uri)
   at System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetPartHelper(Uri partUri)
   at System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetPart(Uri partUri)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.CachedResponse.GetResponseStream()
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.get_ContentType()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId, Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream& unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.EndInit()
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.WPF.InstanceBuilders.WpfBitmapCache.GetImageSource(Uri sourceUri)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.WPF.InstanceBuilders.BitmapImageInstanceBuilder.InitializeImageSource(IInstanceBuilderContext context, DocumentNode valueNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.WPF.InstanceBuilders.BitmapImageInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.Core.ViewNodeManager.Instantiate(ViewNode viewNode)
```

LCP.ScanLite.WindowsWPF is my assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the Problem. I change the Assembly name, and all the Image in the Page were link to the old name.